# How to fetch data from discord

Tags: java, fetch, discord

I would like to know how can I fetch data from discord specifically Number of people in a channel. for example, squad #14 has 3 out of 4 people. I want to fetch that number and display it somewhere in a site. How would I do that?

Regards.

Comment: Here is the [Discord documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro) what have you tried so far?

Comment: @m0skit0 [tag:discord], that said please provide code you've tried, what Library you're using etc. If you want help to get started with your Library I'd recommend looking at its Documentation. This question is too broad for StackOverflow though, you should try asking it in [Discord API, a Discord server for API questions](https://discord.gg/discord-api) though, they will be able to help you there. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17912412)

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with javascript, I'd recommend [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/)

This library can be run through javascript, as well as node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Discord doesn't provide an official way of getting members in a voice channel from the REST API as far as I can tell. To achieve this you will likely need to run a full-blown bot and invite it to your guild. For Java I recommend the [JDA](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA) library.

```java
public class ReadyListener implements EventListener
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws LoginException, RateLimitedException, InterruptedException
    {
        // Note: It is important to register your ReadyListener before building
        JDA jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT)
            .setToken("token")
            .addEventListener(new ReadyListener())
            .buildBlocking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event)
    {
        if (event instanceof ReadyEvent)
        {
            System.out.println("API is ready!");

            // Get a specific voice channel
            event.getJda().getVoiceChannelById("12341234");
        }
    }
}
```

Recommended reading:

https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/3)-Getting-Started

https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro

You will probably want to look at the `VoiceChannel` class in the javadocs.